# How to make an own function for importing csv?

Tags: r, csv

I would like to make a function to import CSV-files:

```r
# function to read csv
myfunc <- function(x){
  paste0(x,"_RAW") <- read.csv(paste0("C:/Users/User/Documents/R/",x,".csv"))
}

einlesen("myvalue")
```

This does not work. What make I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read.csv()` function, which is a variant of `read.table`, returns a data frame.  So, the following version of your function might make more sense:

```
myfunc <- function(x) {
    read.csv(paste0("C:/Users/User/Documents/R/", x, ".csv"))
}

# calling returns a data frame representation of the input CSV file
df <- myfunc("myvalue")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Takes directory path and filename, returns dataframe: 

    read_input_csv <- function(dirpath, filename){

      # Load package: 

      require("readr")

      # Import data: 

      data.frame(read.csv(paste0(dirpath, "/", filename, ifelse(length(grep(".csv", filename)) < 1, ".csv", ""))),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    }

    # Works for both:

tmp <- read_input_csv("~/Example_dir", "example_filename")

tmp <- read_input_csv("~/Example_dir", "example_filename.csv")
```